# CSS Dropdown menu/container?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm planning to do a new sort of dropdown menu style but I'm unsure of how to do it, I want it so that it basically dropsdown a container.

I've kinda marked it out, but I'm unsure on how to do it?

[image]
[image]
HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Enter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    a:visited, a:link, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #4a8fbc;
}

div.nav {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    line-height: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #256690;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwRJ2/

Comment: post your code too not just images also create a fiddle

Comment: Where is you javascript? Where is the code you wrote for drop-down menu

Comment: @Mahasish: It's possible to do this without Javascript

Comment: @try-catch-finally : Yeah!! But the CSS code posted doesn't seem to have any hint of drop-down menu. It simply contains the styling of header.

Comment: @Mahasish: I see this too, but... let me cite him `"I've kinda marked it out, but I'm unsure on how to do it?"`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a good start :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/UwRJ2/4/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>lala</li>
                    <li>lala</li>
                    <li>lala</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS* I added to your existing code + I also changed the display property on the li elements to `display:inline-block;` :

```
ul li > ul{
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
}

ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone I didnd't include the dropdown code because I didn't know where to start in doing this.  Thanks @web-tiki for the reply, this definitely got it started, but now how would I do it so that when I hover over a button I can go down to another link without the container disparaging, as if im still hovering over the button? http://jsfiddle.net/UwRJ2/9/    thanks a lot

Comment: @user3399851 you need to add `display:inline-block;` to the li elements. and make shure that there is no space between the 2nd level <ul> and the parent li http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/UwRJ2/11/